# Why is the heavy crossbow's weight so ridiculous high?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

Hand crossbow deals 1d6 damage, has range 30/120 and weighs 3 lb.
Light crossbow deals 1d8 damage, has range 80/320 and weighs 5 lb.
Heavy crossbow deals 1d10 damage, has range 100/400 and weighs **18 lb.**
[image]

The weight difference looks ridiculous. Why is it like this?

Comment: Um. What does the word "heavy" mean to you?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It is not whining. I just couldn't understand why the difference was so huge. I am not questioning the authors.

Comment: Based on the terms used "weight so ridiculous high?" that's the message I received from your question.  I may have read something into that.  With that comment deleted ... what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't have an "in game" answer per se, but I *DO* have a real world answer.

**Game answer**: "We thought these were a good model for the real world analogue."

**Real life answer**: Since the mechanisms that allow the bolt to be shot with additional force (thus causing more damage) are heavy, the weight increases. Look at this picture of a heavy crossbow:

[image: heavy crossbow]

And this one of a light crossbow:

[image: light crossbow]

These mechanisms of the heavy crossbow are made of metal and wood that can take repeated winding and firing, and are complex and take up more room. The mechanisms for the light crossbow are simpler and have less moving parts. If you want something lighter, try getting one made of other materials such as bone, sinew, (known) alloys, and/or composites. In a more modern setting these could be lightened even further by using rubber, nano carbon tube technology, and alloys. Keep in mind that altering the materials of a crossbow (regardless of heavy or light) may impact the crossbow's durability, as well as the rate of fire, distance, and/or damage of the bolts.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: While rather difficult to find, given how everyone wants to talk about *draw* weight, searching suggests that arbalests (definitely on the heavy side for crossbows outside of anti-siege situations) come in around 10 lbs. An extra 80% is a rather massive increase in weight that I think this answer should address; it does *not* seem that real-world crossbows are 18 lbs.

Comment: And more searching suggests that the windlass (the separate piece used to draw the crossbow) could weigh 5 lbs. Together 15 lbs. is still well short of 18, but the discrepancy is small enough to chalk it up to being particularly heavy even by the standards of heavy crossbows, plus wiggle room for the game not being all that accurate to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

### Different materials, different weight

There isn't a RAW answer here (besides "well, it has the word *heavy* in the name"), so any answer here is going to be speculative.

*Actual* crossbows have been made of all kinds of different materials, with different amounts of power and durability behind them. The heaviest of historical crossbows had metal crossbars and couldn't even be loaded by a single person unassisted and had to have cranks and mechanisms either built in or carried with the weapon. On the lighter side, some crossbows were made with wooden crossbars that weren't much harder to pull back than a standard bow.

So, that extra damage and range *could* be chalked up to the difference between a wooden and a metal crossbar, and/or the loading mechanism required to pull back against such a strong spring.

More information on the construction and materials of different types of crossbows can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbow#Construction

Answer (score 0):

For each % gain in the power, range and ability to launch darts of greater  weight.... IE the bows ballistic potential... Then there must be a decidely non linear increase in the weight of the bow. The only exception would be if you changed the composition of the materials the bow was made of.

Example: You are creating x units of energy harnessed in the draw. the string, the superstructure and the bow beams thickness (using the available materials of the time) will increase in an escalating multiplier. So 30lbs of draw might need a bow beam and superstructure weighing 10lbs but 40lbs of draw would need a bow beam and superstructure weighing 25lbs. 50lbs of draw woulds need a bow weighing in at 60lbs.

The multiplier would continue to grow in a rising curve until the benefit  or gain in ballistics would be made impractical by the weight of the bow needed to restrain that level of unreleased energy or ballistic potential.

Comment: Having actually fired bows (albeit not crossbows) with draw weights ranging from 15 to 65 lbs, I find this unconvincing. If anything, there's a certain amount of *sublinearity*, probably because there are structural elements necessary just to hold, aim, and fire that do not scale with draw weight at all. There is absolutely no reason to suppose inherent structural *superlinear* scaling.

Comment: @TuggyNE when I shot bows (I've never set one on fire), the people drawing the heavier bows tended to be bigger. A crossbow includes the means to hold the pressure, and a heavy crossbow includes a geared mechanism to draw the string back because it is heavier than a human can pull, both of which add weight beyond the limbs.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Indeed, but neither of those has anything to do with the main structure needing to be increasingly stronger for the draw weight. If the answer had said that I would be fine with it, but it doesn't.